Using a prediction from a First Principles Model in a second, statistical model to improve accuracy
I am trying to figure out what this is called, so I can do some reading on it and see which types of statistical models excel in this framework (and known pitfalls to avoid).  I have been calling it a "multi-layered" approach:
Consider an engineering model with a response variable corresponding to a real, physical quantity.  The simplest first principle models for this quantity make a number of questionable assumptions, and the prediction error is in the 15-20% range on average.
Purely empirical models of this process are infeasible due to limited #s of available observations, so the idea would be to reduce training times by building a statistical model off the original, first principles prediction.
So now, we take the first principles prediction, along with additional physical properties (some of which are used in the first principles prediction, most of which are not but are possibly relevant to the response in some form), and build a statistical model to further reduce error.
Call the first principles prediction the "Layer A" prediction, and the final statistical prediction the "Layer B" prediction
This approach definitely reduces error.  Furthermore, Layer B errors are lower than a purely statistical model which doesn't include the Layer A prediction - so it's not just that the statistical model 'skips over' Layer A (i.e., Layer A is required to provide the lowest error).
So the question is, what is this approach called?
What models perform best in this framework?  What are important things to consider/pitfalls to avoid?
So far, basic random forest models have produced the lowest errors, even lower than xgboost.  I think the RF models excel in this approach because of how the variables are sampled in each new tree.  The model ends up being forced to not use the Layer A prediction some % of the time, and figure out which other variables are relevant.  Whereas something like xgboost builds the trees sequentially, and probably keeps identifying the Layer A prediction as most relevant, and keeps wanting to use it despite it's moderate error.  So the Layer A error ends up being more baked in.
